# What exactly is meant by 1 additional hit die?

Tags: dnd-5e, character-advancement

The dnd5e starter set explains that when you levelup you are rolling for your additional hp you gain. But for the sheets is stated, that you get 1 additional die with each level.

Now for me the following isn't clear: Does this mean with each levelup I roll an additional die? Like for lvling up to 2 rolling 1d8 to determine the increase and leveling to level 3 rolling 2d8 to determine the next increase?

Or is this just another wording for "Don't forget that with each level your HP increase!"

Comment: [Related] [How can I associate Hit Dice with healing?](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/44516)

Comment: Hmm I'm pretty sure there's a dupe of this somewhere, I remember the increasing-dice error being discussed before.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

They are two separate things. Let's say you are a Rogue (1d8). When you level up, you roll 1d8 to determine your HP increment, no matter what your level is. Also, you have a reserve of dice (d8). When you perform a short rest, you can roll one or more of those dice in order to recover HP. The higher your level, the larger your dice reserve (at each levelup, you get 1 additional die for this reserve).